# Stripe unpaid status

Tags: stripe-payments, pyrocms

In my Pyro CMS project, I am using Stripe payment gateway, while testing product's payment in test environment, all things go smooth but in live, I am getting a lot of unpaid order status. When is this status flag set? Is there any way that i can track the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem. When a customer checkout the products and reach payment page but, doesnot pays or proceed further, the status remains unpaid which is default case**(had customer proceeded and placed credit card details, the status would have changed to failed or paid according to the validity of credit card)**. The order is placed but not paid. So if someone gives just try out to the whole thing, we see a lot of Unpaid orders...